# svg package interfers with opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, transparency, svg

As soon as I load the package **svg**, tikz does not handle **opacity** any longer.

Here, an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{svg} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[fill=red,opacity=0.5] (1,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will yield:

[image: wrong]

Without `\usepackage{svg}`, opacity will be displayed correctly:

[image: correct]

In the log file, the following package versions are listed:

- everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00
- pgfrcs 2013/12/20 v3.0.0
- pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0
- graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f
- keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13
- graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o
- trig 1999/03/16 v1.09
- infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3
- ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22
- pgfsys 2013/11/30 v3.0.0
- xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11
- pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.0
- pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.0
- pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.0
- pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.0
- tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0
- pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20
- ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3
- ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3
- epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5
- grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1
- kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3
- kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11
- kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16
- etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5

If `\usepackage{svg}` is loaded, the log file includes also:

- svg 2012/09/05 v1.0
- xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b
- subfig 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3
- caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89
- caption3 2013/05/02 v1.6-88
- import 2009/03/23  v 5.1
- transparent 2007/01/08 v1.0
- auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3

Thanks for any hints to solve this problem!

Comment: transparent is the source of the problem.

Comment: This is very odd. The opacity works with me, but it stops working if I change the document class to `standalone`.

Comment: @ulrike Is there a way to force the svg package not to load the transparent package?

Comment: @john I tried to load xcolor before loading tikz and svg, but it does not do any difference.

Comment: You can use `\expandafter\def\csname ver@transparent.sty\endcsname{}` before loading svg. But I have no idea if svg needs transparent.sty.

Comment: @ulrike That works! Perfect!

Comment: The same problem occurs when using package _ctable_. Also here, the answer from Ulrike works perfectly.

Comment: I've just found the same issue (I'm loading the `memoir` class). Ulrike's suggestion worked for me, too. Shouldn't it be turned into an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update

newer version of the transparent package avoid the clash and the work-around is no longer needed.

### Old answer

The transparent package, loaded by svg, clashes with the tikz code for opacity. As a workaround you can try to suppress the loading of transparent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@transparent.sty\endcsname{}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[fill=red,opacity=0.5] (1,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since version 2.00 of `svg`, the loading of `transparent` can also be disabled with the `svg` package option `notransparent` (or `usetransparent=false`).