# svg removes opacity handling from beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, transparency, svg

When imported `svg` into a beamer presentation that uses `\pgfsetfillopacity`, semi transparency stops working.

For example the code below produces different results with and without loading the package

Without the `svg` package:

[image]

With the `svg` package:

[image]

Is there a way to patch `svg` or a workaround to use it with beamer  semitransparent features? (or maybe the problem is related to `pgf`?)

```
    % code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44716/7561
    \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
    \usecolortheme{rose}

    % switch this on or off
    %\usepackage{svg}

    \usebackgroundtemplate{\centering
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}

    \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
    \addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
    \addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

    \begin{document}

      \begin{frame}{}
        \begin{theorem}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. 
        \end{theorem}

      \begin{alertblock}{Alert!!!}
    Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      \end{alertblock}

      \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
    Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros.
      \end{exampleblock}
      \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Extended example, that includes an `.svg` file.

```
% code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44716/7561
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
width="19.581747mm"
height="37.898418mm"
viewBox="0 0 69.384143 134.28573"
id="svg2"
version="1.1"
inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
sodipodi:docname="example.svg">
<defs
id="defs4" />
<sodipodi:namedview
id="base"
pagecolor="#ffffff"
bordercolor="#666666"
borderopacity="1.0"
inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
inkscape:pageshadow="2"
inkscape:zoom="0.35"
inkscape:cx="-280.71427"
inkscape:cy="48.571435"
inkscape:document-units="px"
inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
showgrid="false"
fit-margin-top="0"
fit-margin-left="0"
fit-margin-right="0"
fit-margin-bottom="0"
inkscape:window-width="1331"
inkscape:window-height="750"
inkscape:window-x="29"
inkscape:window-y="18"
inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
<metadata
id="metadata7">
<rdf:RDF>
<cc:Work
rdf:about="">
<dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
<dc:type
rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
<dc:title></dc:title>
</cc:Work>
</rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g
inkscape:label="Layer 1"
inkscape:groupmode="layer"
id="layer1"
transform="translate(-254.2857,-446.64791)">
<path
style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
d="m 271.42857,580.93363 c 62.85714,-37.14285 51.42857,-85.71428 51.42857,-85.71428 l -68.57143,-48.57143 31.42858,71.42857 z"
id="path4136"
inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
</g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents*}


\usecolortheme{rose}

% this definition creates an error on the last frame
\makeatletter
  \@namedef{transparent}%
\makeatother

% switch this on or off
\usepackage{svg}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\centering
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{theorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. 
    \end{theorem}

  \begin{alertblock}{Alert!!!}
Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  \end{alertblock}

  \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros.
  \end{exampleblock}
  \end{frame}

  % this produces an error when \@namedef is used
  \begin{frame}
    \includesvg{sample}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The source of the problem is, that the svg package load `\RequirePackage{transparent}`.

Comment: Possible workaround: make a copy of `svg.sty` to your working directory, rename it and comment out line 43 `\@ifpackageloaded{transparent}{}{\RequirePackage{transparent}}%` and  use `\usepackage{my_svg}`. This will probably give issues with transparency in svgs...

Comment: Or simply convert your svgs before compiling and include the pdf?

Comment: I thought that `transparent` was the culprit. However, I don't want to lose the full svg auto-conversion capability. As that is the idea of using the package in the first place. Any idea, if there is another way of using the `transparent` package with `pgf`?

Comment: I have no idea how `transparent` and `pgf` interact. But can you try if the method without `transparent` works for your svgs?

Comment: Beamer doesn't use real transparency. I am not sure about PGF. `transparent` is enabling transparency in the PDF colour stack directly. Beamer creates transparency by mixing with the background colour. I don't know what PGF does.

Comment: PGF is also doing it in the PDF. At a rough guess, it and `transparent` are competing with each other to inject code into the PDF in ways which conflict e.g. one overwriting the other or something like that. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Do you know if there is any equivalent package that allows me to compile `.svg` on the fly? or to use the `transparent` package with `pgf`?

Comment: Just to save others the time for trying: `tcolorbox` has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

New solution based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390317/36296

```
% code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44716/7561
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390317/36296
\expandafter\def\csname ver@transparent.sty\endcsname{}

% switch this on or off
\usepackage{svg}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\centering
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{theorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. 
    \end{theorem}

  \begin{alertblock}{Alert!!!}
Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  \end{alertblock}

  \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros.
  \end{exampleblock}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Replacing the troublesome `svg` package with https://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg-inkscape work - this needs `inkscape` to be installed, but looking at the creator of your sample svg, this should not be a problem.

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: true}
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
width="19.581747mm"
height="37.898418mm"
viewBox="0 0 69.384143 134.28573"
id="svg2"
version="1.1"
inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
sodipodi:docname="example.svg">
<defs
id="defs4" />
<sodipodi:namedview
id="base"
pagecolor="#ffffff"
bordercolor="#666666"
borderopacity="1.0"
inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
inkscape:pageshadow="2"
inkscape:zoom="0.35"
inkscape:cx="-280.71427"
inkscape:cy="48.571435"
inkscape:document-units="px"
inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
showgrid="false"
fit-margin-top="0"
fit-margin-left="0"
fit-margin-right="0"
fit-margin-bottom="0"
inkscape:window-width="1331"
inkscape:window-height="750"
inkscape:window-x="29"
inkscape:window-y="18"
inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
<metadata
id="metadata7">
<rdf:RDF>
<cc:Work
rdf:about="">
<dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
<dc:type
rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
<dc:title></dc:title>
</cc:Work>
</rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g
inkscape:label="Layer 1"
inkscape:groupmode="layer"
id="layer1"
transform="translate(-254.2857,-446.64791)">
<path
style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
d="m 271.42857,580.93363 c 62.85714,-37.14285 51.42857,-85.71428 51.42857,-85.71428 l -68.57143,-48.57143 31.42858,71.42857 z"
id="path4136"
inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
</g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents*}


\usecolortheme{rose}


\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{%
 \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}%
 {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0%
 {\immediate\write18{#3}}\fi%
}

\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
 \executeiffilenewer{#1.svg}{#1.pdf}%
 {inkscape -z -D --file=#1.svg %
 --export-pdf=#1.pdf --export-latex}%
 \input{#1.pdf_tex}%
}


\usebackgroundtemplate{\centering
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{theorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. 
    \end{theorem}

  \begin{alertblock}{Alert!!!}
Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  \end{alertblock}

  \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros.
  \end{exampleblock}
  \end{frame}

  % this produces an error when \@namedef is used
  \begin{frame}
    \includesvg{sample}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The workaround works when no `\includesvg` is used. But when that command exist, it is not found. It seems that the `\@namedef` messes up the macros from the `svg` package. See my updated example

Comment: @adn See my new workaround