# Error when displaying page in PDF viewer or Printing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, svg, shadows

I try to print a PDF which includes some TIKZ figures but the printing service has an issue to print them.

To find the cullprit we try to reduce our template to a minimum and found an problem with TIKZ shadows and the svg package.

We are not able to reproduce the error and the printing service has Acrobot Pro 9, which only complains when printing is started. It shows an error page content can not be shown. 
So to get hold of the problem we found out that watching the files with an old adobe 8.3 reader does not render the files and show only a blank page.

following a MWE

```
\pdfminorversion=3
\documentclass[ border=5pt ]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

% removing svg solves the problem
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}%

\tikzstyle{abstract}=[
fill=black!15!white, 
drop shadow,
]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]%
    \node[abstract](iasPortObj){\textbf{MinimaTestObject}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

Also enforcing pdf version 1.3 does not help.

When removing the svg packet the page also shows in acrobat 8.3. 
When removing shadows it also works when svg is loaded.

It seems there is a issue with tikz produced figures and svg packet.

[image: MWE is displayed]
[image: MWE not displayed]

The problem is that all our PDF viewer show the PDF properly.
We can print it on our printer.

The error is issued when the print service try to print this PDF.

We have this issue with multiple pdf.

Converting them with ghostscript solved the problem for some of them, but not all.

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
```

1.) Is this a known incompatibility of svg and TKIZ or shadows?

2.) We search a proper way to ensure a finelizing process which garantees that the printing service will have no problem and the printed version looks like we see it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The svg packages causes problems if the document contains transparent objects. My usual workaround is to not use the svg package, but use inkscape to convert the svg to tex, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327675/svg-removes-opacity-handling-from-beamer/331416#331416 (not the same issue, but describes how to bypass the svg package) or if on mac, open the pdf created by tex with `preview.app` and save again.

Comment: Does your drawing (and shadow) have any control points that are outside the printable area? Aside: One major American P.O.D. service discourages vector artwork (of any kind) due to frequent problems in rasterization. If your drawing will be printed to paper at a specific size, it may be better to place the drawing as a raster image at 300dpi resolution, grayscale (not RBG). Convert the svg to raster in Inkscape or Gimp.